# JavaScript DOM Dependent on Viewport Causing Strange Results

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-chrome, dom

I am trying to find occurrences of a string in another string that has been pulled from the HTML document. The page is an SNMP monitor but we have been having issues in the past with CTRL + F because it only wants to find the string within the current viewport of the browser. My attempt at getting around this and not having to look through things manually was to write a script.

The issue here is that it appears the docHTML variable is only able to hold so much data and anything else is truncated. I have looked around on Stack Overflow and found that my string size is significantly less than other people have tried, so that shouldn't be the issue.

All of the IP addresses in the 'ipArray' variable do exist on the page in different locations and are in the docHTML variable when I look through it myself. When I run the doSearch function at various points in the page (viewport dependent) it gives me different results.

I really don't know what has gone wrong here as the code does work sometimes, and not other times. My goal is to have the code go through the whole page and find all missing IP's and add them to the array so that we can go ahead and add them instead of having to compare 490 IP's on a spreadsheet to up to 490 in the monitoring utility.

Thanks in advance!

```
var docHTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
var missing = [];

function doSearch(text) {
        if (docHTML.search(text) == -1){
            missing.push(text);
        }
}

var ipArray = [
"192.168.64.236",
"192.168.64.237",
"192.168.64.238",
"192.168.64.10",
"192.168.64.11",
"192.168.64.12",
"192.168.65.40",
"192.168.65.47"
];

var Total = ipArray.length;

for(i=0;i<Total;i++){
    doSearch(ipArray[i]);
}

console.log("Missing IP's: " + (Total - missing.length));
console.log(missing);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? Are you running this code on page load?

Comment: @bozzmob I am running the code as a bookmarklet, or through the console. I am attempting to take the output of the HTML and convert it to a string, then look through the string for specific occurrences of other strings as found in the ipArray. The code works fine, but only seems to find the strings when they are visible through the view port on the page. If you scroll down the code fails to work.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Not really sure why you are getting inconsistent results. I am checking it now with some stub data. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works as intended. The issue happened to be the SNMP monitor it is running on top of. Everything on the page seems to be loaded by POST requests as you scroll. It seems to grab a few before and after which was why I was able to see it in the code and not when executing.

Comment: Awesome! Yesterday I worked on this for quite some time. It perfectly worked for me. But, then I thought there was some other problem w.r.t. parsing or something.

Comment: @bozzmob Yes, it was very strange. I appreciate you taking the time to look at it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, not much of change, just a tweak to your logging statement. You were printing "total-missing" which is wrong. What we need is the missing count-

```
var docHTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
var missing = [];

function doSearch(text) {
        if (docHTML.search(text) == -1){
            missing.push(text);
        }
}

var ipArray = [
"69.171.224.11",
"199.59.149.230",
"174.121.194.34",
"209.200.154.225",
"69.174.244.50",
"67.201.54.151"
];

var Total = ipArray.length;

console.log(Total);

for(i=0;i<Total;i++){
    doSearch(ipArray[i]);
}

console.log("Missing IP's: " + (missing.length)); /***HERE***/
console.log(missing);
```

Other than this, the whole code worked for me as expected. Let me know what else/exactly is the issue. Happy to help.

Comment: I noticed the number there was incorrect, but it is still the content in the missing array which is wrong for me. For example, if I am at the top of the page it will give me 4 results in the array, if I scroll to the middle of the page and re-run the code I may get 2 results.